# Loader is not working in FullCalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using FullCalendar(http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin with AngularJs I need to show a loader when data is loading to calendar. I am using loading trigger to show loader

```
$scope.uiConfig = {loading: $scope.loading}
$scope.loading = function( isLoading, view ) {
          if(isLoading) {// isLoading gives boolean value
              $('#loading').show();
          } else {
              $('#loading').hide();
          }
        }
```

Explain how it works

Comment: you can use `loading` callback  if your loading the data for fullcalendar using ajax, http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/

Comment: can you give me an example for it?

Comment: here is an simple example at jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/XPe2q/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loading` callback of fullcalendar is triggered when events fetching starts/stops.

`function( isLoading, view ){} //isLoading is true when events fetching //is started else false when done`

**JS CODE:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  year: 2010,
  month: 0, // January
  editable: true,
  events: '/gh/gist/response.json/6218404/',
  loading: function( isLoading, view ) {
      if(isLoading) {// isLoading gives boolean value
          $('#wait').show();
      } else {
          $('#wait').hide();
      }
  }
});
```

[Working demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/XPe2q/19/)

References:

- [`loading:` callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading)

Comment: the loading callback url is broken, please fix it

Comment: docs were changed, so link was broken.

@user2342558, you can always check the official docs for the latest API spec